# Datefield modification Extjs4?

Tags: extjs, calendar, extjs4, datefield

Is it possible to set the datefield in Extjs4 to be opend by default, to only have a small calendar with today date selected, to somehow skip clicking a datefield button to open a calendar and to hide a textfield in datefield??

[image]

[image: calendar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use the Ext.picker.Date class, the field.Date uses it internally for the calendar.